# CGAffineTransformMakeRotation and Autolayout issues under iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

After applying a rotation transformation on a simple UIView

```
CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * -0.5);

simpleVIew_.transform = trans;
```

Which has the following constraints

```
[self addConstraints:@[
   [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: simpleView_ attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                   toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                               multiplier:1 constant:50],

   [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: simpleView_ attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                   toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                               multiplier:1 constant:270],

   [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: simpleView_ attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                   toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                               multiplier:1.0 constant:0],

   [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: simpleView_ attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                   toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                               multiplier:1.0 constant:0]

]];
```

I get two different results between iOS7.1 and iOS8 beta 5:

iOS7.1

```
<UIView: 0x1655d990; frame = (0 30; 50 270); transform = [0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0]; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1655dab0>
```

iOS8 beta 5

```
<UIView: 0x16e5a530; frame = (-110 140; 270 50); transform = [0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0]; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x16e61880>>
```

Notice the differences in the frame - the width/height values have switched and the x,y coordinates have changed.

Any ideas why there's such a huge difference between 7.1 and 8?

Comment: I have a similar issue and I'm almost completely certain it's due to how they have made everything interface oriented in iOS 8 (basically changing how the origin point for coordinate systems is determined) but I haven't quite nailed down if that's it, or if there's a bug in iOS 8, or what. For now I've modified the one small section of my app that uses rotation to use calculated CGRects (ugh)

Comment: Any solution to this issue?

Comment: Nothing yet, need to check the latest iOS8 release.. I will update.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet? I haven't...upvoted your question.

Comment: Nothing yet, have u checked this on iOS 8 GM?

Comment: I have this issue also with a scale transform.

Answer (score 3):

*Not really a solution but more of a work around.*

I have found that top, bottom, left, and right constraints behave differently when building on iOS 8 vs iOS 7 when using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation. However, CenterX and CenterY behave the same for each. Also, height and width constraints will behave the same as long as you `addConstraint` to the same view you `constraintWithItem`.

So, if you can change your constraints for a view that uses CGAffineTransformMakeRotation to only use height, width, CenterX, CenterY, then you should be able to have the same constraints appear the same when building on both iOS versions.

Below is an exert from my own code, which was giving me the same layout regardless of iOS version:

```
// Rotate View 90º
endorseHereLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-(M_PI)/2);

[self addSubview:endorseHereLabel];
[self bringSubviewToFront:endorseHereLabel];

// Configure Constraints
[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:endorseHereLabel
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                    toItem:lineView1
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                  constant:40.0]];
[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:endorseHereLabel
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                    toItem:lineView1
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                  constant:kBottomBuffer]];
[endorseHereLabel addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:endorseHereLabel
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                toItem:nil
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                            multiplier:1.0
                                                              constant:12.0]];
[endorseHereLabel addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:endorseHereLabel
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                toItem:nil
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                            multiplier:1.0
                                                              constant:250.0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the simple view to a container view. I've seen similar issues in at least two of my views and in both cases adding them to a container view seems to fix the problem.

**Edit**

What I mean by a container view, is simply adding the simple view to a UIView, then apply the constraints and rotation to the container instead.

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/transform)

> @property(nonatomic) CGAffineTransform transform
>
> The origin of the transform is the value of the center property, or
>   the layer’s anchorPoint property if it was changed. (Use the layer
>   property to get the underlying Core Animation layer object.) The
>   default value is CGAffineTransformIdentity.

You need to set the anchor point of your view before rotation.

> yourView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);

Values must be between 0 and 1.

[image]

[Sample here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/9864/how-to-create-a-rotating-wheel-control-with-uikit)

May be changed default value CGAffineTransformIdentity?